# Jinja2 Child content not showing up

Tags: python-3.x, templates, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, jinja2

Thanks for the help!
So, I'm trying to create a simple layout with a Bootstrap nav-bar and a block of content on the body, and that works fine. But, when I extend that to a child, no matter what changes I make on the child, nothing shows up!
I'll post the two templates I'm using right now.

layout.html

```
    <!doctype html>
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} </title>
    </head>
<body>
{% block navbar %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-fixed-stop" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BGP Monitor</a></div>
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('admin_control') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
<div class="container-fluid" id="form">
    {% block container %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the child:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h3>aaa</h3>
{% block container %}
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="container">
    {{ super() }}
<form action="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email(class="form-control", placeholder="Username") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password(class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

The nav-bar shows, but the form doesn't show up, at all. It's as if the child does not exist.
Any ideas?
Thank you

P.S:
So, I changed to this:
layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-fixed-stop" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BGP Monitor</a></div>
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('admin_control') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    {% block container %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this child:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block container %}
<form action="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email(class="form-control", placeholder="Username") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password(class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This way, there's no duplicate {% extend ... %}.
It now shows the form, but the WHOLE div is clickable, rendering it pretty much useless..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't supposed to have all the `<html><head><body>` tags in a child.  It should just be:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block container %}
<h3>aaa</h3>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="container">
    {{ super() }}
<form action="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email(class="form-control", placeholder="Username") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password(class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And notice how I moved the `<h3>aaa</h3>` code to inside the `block`.

Next, you can only have one `{% extends ... %}` call per rendering (You can't extend an extension).  So, you need to consolidate your child to `layout.html`, making separate layouts per view.

Alternatively, you could change `layout.html` to use an include, keeping just one `{% extends... %}` per view:

layout.html

```
{% include "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-fixed-stop" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BGP Monitor</a></div>
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('admin_control') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{% endblock %}
<div class="container-fluid" id="form">
    {% block container %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Again, notice there are no duplicated `<html> etc` tags in `layout.html`.  Those are already in `bootstrap/base.html`

Comment: I've tried that, but still doesn't show up.
However, if I change 'container' for 'content' on the child, it does show up, but then everything is clickable on that div/form.
For example, if I try to insert the email, it'll send a POST request as soon as I click on the email field.
I have no clue what's going on.

Comment: Updated answer:  You can only have one {% extends ... %} call per rendering (You can't extend an extension). So, you need to consolidate your `child` with `layout.html`, making separate layouts per view. (e.g. `layout_form.html`)

Comment: I updated my post, it no longer has an extension calling another one.
It now does show the form, but the whole thing is clickable :/

Comment: I suggest opening the page in your browser, viewing the source code, and troubleshooting it there.  Try removing `super()`, and change `id="form"` to `id="my_form"` to avoid name conflicts

Comment: With your new changes, shouldn't `{% extends "layout.html" %}` be `{% extends "template.html" %}`?

Comment: Sorry, I actually named it wrong when I pasted here.
But the layout now shows correctly, so does the form. But the whole <div> is clickable and thus renders it useless

Comment: Then you should mark this as answered, and open a new question about the clickable DIV.  Make sure you post the source code from the browser.

Comment: Could you edit your answer so I can accept it? As it stands it is incorrect and I don't want to mislead other people! Cheers and thanks for the help